# Sylius taxonomy bundle not compatible with symfony 3.3.8

Tags: symfony, sylius, symfony-3.3

I install Symofny 3.3.8 and try to install
composer require sylius/taxonomy-bundle and
composer require sylius/resource-bundle

I got error.

> Problem 1
>   - sylius/taxonomy-bundle v0.18.0 requires sylius/resource-bundle ^0.18 -> satisfiable by sylius/resource-bundle[v0.18.0].
>   - Installation request for sylius/taxonomy-bundle ^0.18.0 -> satisfiable by sylius/taxonomy-bundle[v0.18.0].
>   - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.3.8
>   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.8
>   - sylius/resource-bundle v0.18.0 requires symfony/validator ^2.7 -> satisfiable by symfony/validator[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11,
>   v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18,
>   v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25,
>   v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32,
>   v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9,
>   v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15,
>   v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22,
>   v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5,
>   v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
>   - don't install symfony/validator v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.8

[image]

Comment: You should rephrase your post so that it had a question that we could address.

Comment: And show your composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are requesting the latest 'stable' versions, which currently are `0.18`. These versions are not compatible with the latest versions of Symfony and are actually rather old. Version 0.18 is released halfway 2016 actually. If you set the version requirements to `^1.0.0@dev`, you will get the latest bundles released as beta versions, which could be a good starting point for now.

So if you do this: `composer require sylius/taxonomy:^1.0.0@dev`, you will get the beta3 version for 1.0.

The RC versions of Sylius (which are currently being tested while writing this answer) are not published to the subtree splits (which is the place you are requesting the code from). Tomorrow Sylius 1.0 will be released, then it should be easy to require the version 1.0: `composer require sylius/taxonomy:^1.0`.

If you want the latest version now (master branch): `composer require sylius/taxonomy:dev-master`. Be aware this might be unstable normally, but today it should be ok if you upgrade tomorrow to use version `1.0`.